# MariaDB auto update from Firebase when data change?

Tags: c#, database, firebase, mariadb, auto-update

I'm a beginner and currently I use `Firebase` so the value of a key changes from "Not Used" to "Used" when the client registers the key.
I want to use a database like `MariaDB`, but I want to auto update the state of a key in `MariaDB` when the state changes in Firebase. Is there any way to connect a database to Firebase and trigger an update event when the state changes in Firebase?

Or alternatively forget the Firebase and change directly in the database when client registers a key?

I expect an auto update in database when the client registers the key, so I can search for the key and see the current state, using an application made in WinForms/WPF.

I already search, but didn't find any real solution that worked or that I did understand

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Firebase to synchronize with MariaDB, but since both databases provide APIs to access them, you can build something yourself.

You can [listen for changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#listen_for_events) in Firebase in your client-side application code, and write it to MariaDB from there.

Alternative, you can use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to [listen for changes to the Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) and then write to MariaDB from there. While this is more complex to set up initially, it has the advantage that it then runs on Google's servers - so it'll continue to work even when the client is not running your application code.